# Closing JInternalFrame with JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing

I want to close the JInternalFrame.I am developing A MenuItem as Crete,whenever click on open it is opening an JInternalFrame,but it's not closing.

Please help me.
Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class CloseWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JTextArea tx;
int i=1;
public CloseWindow() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Crete = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    Crete.setText("Create");
    Crete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            CreteActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(Crete);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 427, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void CreteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame();
    internalFrame.setName("Document"+i);
    internalFrame.setClosable(true);
    i++;
    internalFrame.setSize(700, 700);
    tx = new JTextArea();
    internalFrame.add(tx);

    tPane.add(internalFrame);
    internalFrame.setSize(internalFrame.getMaximumSize());
    internalFrame.pack();
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);

}                                     

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CloseWindow().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Crete;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tPane;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, if it has helped you, or comment if not. =)

Comment: FYI `JInternalFrames` should be used with `JDesktopPane`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following:

```
    internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            tPane.remove(internalFrame);
        }
    });
```

But don't forget to make `internalFrame` variable to be `final`.